# CustomAuthorize Attribute Not Updating After Adding/Changing User

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm having an issue with an internal MVC site. I may have titled this wrong as I don't know exactly where the issue lies. I have the following custom authorize attribute:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(params string[] roles)
    {
        using (var dataLayer = new CarrierBoundEntities())
        {
            string userNames = string.Empty;

            foreach (var user in dataLayer.tbl_PremiumWriteOffs_Users)
            {
                if (roles.Contains(user.Role))
                {
                    userNames += user.Username + ",";
                }
            }

            if (userNames.Length > 0)
            {
                // Remove last comma
                userNames.Remove(userNames.Length - 1);
            }

            Users = userNames;
        }
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

The datalayer is the default DbContext created by the Entity Framework. There is a view that allows users with an admin role to add/edit users. Here is the controller that handles a post to edit a user:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[CustomAuthorize(new string[] { "Admin" })]
public ActionResult UsersEditView(UsersVM viewModel)
{
    using (var dataLayer = new CarrierBoundEntities())
    {
        var userToEdit = dataLayer.tbl_PremiumWriteOffs_Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == viewModel.UserSubmit.ID);

        if (userToEdit == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        // If the username was changed then check and display error if it's the same as another entry
        if (userToEdit.Username.Equals(viewModel.UserSubmit.Username, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == false)
        {
            foreach (var user in dataLayer.tbl_PremiumWriteOffs_Users)
            {
                if (user.Username.Equals(viewModel.UserSubmit.Username, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("UserSubmit.Username", "A user with this username already exists.");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            userToEdit.Username = viewModel.UserSubmit.Username;
            userToEdit.Role = viewModel.UserSubmit.Role;
            userToEdit.UserLastModified = this.User.Identity.Name;
            userToEdit.DateLastModified = DateTime.Now;
            dataLayer.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("UsersView");
        }

        viewModel.RoleSelect = GetRoleSelectList();
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

Now when I run it locally on my machine things work fine, but when deployed on a server something doesn't get updated when a new user is added or the role of an existing user is changed. New users still don't get access to any part of the site, and a user that is changed from admin to user will still have access to the admin areas. It stays this way until the app is restarted on the server.

The odd thing is that after making a change, the change is visible on both the front end and back end, so it seems that both the database and entity context are being updated fine. So I'm thinking it might be the custom authorize attributes that aren't updating with the new list of usernames, but I really have no idea and am having trouble debugging since it works as it should locally.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try remote debugging it on your server. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are trying to extend the `AuthorizeAttribue` is wrong. You need to do something like this:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private string[] _roles;

    public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(params string[] roles)
    {
        _roles = roles;
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var user = httpContext.User;
        var isAuthorized = false;

        // check in the database to see if the user 
        // is in one of the Roles in _roles and therefore authorized...
        if(/* some code to check if the user is authorized */)
        {
           isAuthorized = true;
        }

        return isAuthorized;
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixed my issue thank you! I had picked up that other way somewhere before and it worked fine for a few other projects but suddenly caused issues with this one. Good to know the correct way to extend it.